# How to select all items in a Tkinter ListBox?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I want to create a Button named **Select All** which should select and highlight all the items present in the ListBox.
I tried looking for it, but no information is available for this situation.
Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: if you keep all items of the listbox in some iterable you could iterate over them and set them all to true whenever the select all button is checked

Comment: Thanks bro.I was able to select all items using listbox.select_set(0, END)

Comment: glad to hear it worked! :) And the same works for when you want to deselect as well

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `selection_set` method, passing it the two indexes `0` (zero) and `"end"`.

```
the_listbox.selection_set(0, "end")
```

Comment: Thanks, this issue is solved. Now I wanted to append all these selected items to a list. How to do that?